# Overflow when inserting an specific arithmetic value

Tags: java, aspose.words

I'm currently working on generating a Word document file from a Word Template using data from a JSON variable in java. I'm using the ASPOSE library.

I have a problem with a specific variable. This variable should print a numeric(float) value. However, when the value is 100.0 ,it is sometimes printed as -2147483648 (-2^31) instead of 100.0.

I have to mention that when the value is a double digit float (for example 35.5 and 99.9),the value of the variable is printed correctly. Also when the input value is integer(e.g 100),the correct value is also printed correctly.

I have also tried to use some format strings(<<[variableName]:"0.##">>) inside the expression tag in the Word Template file, but it didn't fix it.

[Here is the DOCX template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzB5c.png)

[This is the input value from JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeqvx.png)

[Here is the generated result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgmLX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aggelos991

Using the latest available version of Aspose.Words for Java (i.e. 22.2), I was unable to reproduce the issue. Moreover, we had [a similar issue](https://forum.aspose.com/t/transform-string-to-number-when-building-report-from-template-word-document-using-linq-reporting-engine-c-json-convert-serialize-object/211513) in the past, so it seems like you are using an outdated version of Aspose.Words for Java. Could you please upgrade to the latest version and let us know if the issue is still present?

Comment: I upgraded to 22.2 version and it worked. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Float type is in the 32bit format, and 100.0 is in the 64bit format(double). 100.0f must be used for proper use.

Comment: This just prints "100.0f" as a string.